# Ошибка 500 из-за ошибок в коде

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, opencart

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки!
Мое колдовство начинается для опенкарт 2 и вот с такого кода в модели:

```
 public function getVendorProduct ($vendor_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("select vproduct_id from ".DB_PREFIX."vendor where vendor = ".$vendor_id);
    //$query = $this->db->query("select vendor, product_id, image, price, name from ".DB_RPEFIX."vendor, ".DB_PREFIX."product, ".DB_PREFIX."product_description where ".DB_RPEFIX."vendor.vendor = ".$vendor_id." and ".DB_RPEFIX."product_description.product_id = ".$qqqqq." and ".DB_PREFIX."product.product_id = ".$qqqqq);
    if ($query) {
            $count_id = count($query);

            $vproducts = array();

            for ($i=0; $i<$count_id; $i++) {
                $sql_products_data = $this->db->query("select product_id, image, price, name from ".DB_PREFIX."product, ".DB_PREFIX."product_description where ".DB_PREFIX."product_description.product_id = ".$query['vproduct_id']." and ".DB_PREFIX."product.product_id = ".$query['vproduct_id']);
            }

            foreach($sql_products_data as $result) {
                $vproducts['prod_id'] = $result['product_id'];
                $vproducts['prod_image'] = $result['image'];
                $vproducts['prod_price'] = $result['price'];
                $vproducts['prod_name'] = $result['name'];
            }

            return $vproducts;
        }
}
```

Далее контроллер:

```
$vendor_product = $this->model_catalog_vendor->getVendorProduct($vendor_id);
        $data['products_list_vendor'][] = array();
        if($vendor_producys) {
            foreach ($vendor_products as $result) {
                $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_id'] = $result['prod_id'];
                $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_image'] = $result['prod_image'];
                $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_price'] = $result['prod_price'];
                $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_name'] = $result['prod_name'];

            }
        }
```

И наконец сам вывод на страницу магазина:

```
<div id="vendor_products">
    <?php forech ($products_list_vendor as $products_list) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $products_list['vproduct_id']; ?></p>
        <p>- - - - - - - - - -</p>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

При таком вот заклятии у меня получается пока что только ошибка 500, как исправить код? Юзал, ответа не нашел

Comment: Откройте журнал ошибок на сервере и посмотрите из-за чего возникает ошибка.

Comment: Проверил и ошибки нет в логе ни какой

Comment: `if($vendor_producys) {` в контроллере это опечатка?

Comment: Да,точно я и заметил, спасибо

Comment: Исправил но все равно ошибка 500

Comment: Еще раз: откройте лог ошибок сервера или включите его если он выключен. При выпадании ошибки 500 она не может быть не зафиксироана в логе. Тем более, что если вы скопировали код в вопрос (а не набрали) то у вас синтаксическая ошибка и она должна быть в логе. И ее __нельзя__ исправлять пока вы не будете уверены, что аналогичные ошибки попадают в лог

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_id; $i++) {
    $sql_products_data = $this->db->query("select product_id, image, price, name from " . DB_PREFIX . "product, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description where " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id'] . " and " . DB_PREFIX . "product.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id']);
}

foreach ($sql_products_data as $result) {
    $vproducts['prod_id'] = $result['product_id'];
    $vproducts['prod_image'] = $result['image'];
    $vproducts['prod_price'] = $result['price'];
    $vproducts['prod_name'] = $result['name'];
}
```

Логическая ошибка.Переменная `$sql_products_data` постоянно перезаписывается в цикле `for`. В нижеследующий цикл `foreach` попадает последний результат обработки.

Возможно, вы хотели написать что-то подобное:

```
$sql_products_data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_id; $i++) {
    $sql_products_data[] = $this->db->query("select product_id, image, price, name from " . DB_PREFIX . "product, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description where " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id'] . " and " . DB_PREFIX . "product.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id']);
}

foreach ($sql_products_data as $result) {
    if ($result) {
        $vproducts['prod_id'] = $result['product_id'];
        $vproducts['prod_image'] = $result['image'];
        $vproducts['prod_price'] = $result['price'];
        $vproducts['prod_name'] = $result['name'];
    }
}
```

---

```
 if ($vendor_producys) {
     foreach ($vendor_products as $result) {
         $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_id'] = $result['prod_id'];
         $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_image'] = $result['prod_image'];
         $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_price'] = $result['prod_price'];
         $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_name'] = $result['prod_name'];

     }
 }
```

В этом коде в условии проверяется переменная `$vendor_producys`, а используется `$vendor_products`. Есть подозрение на опечатку в первом варианте.

---

```
 <div id="vendor_products">
     <?php forech($products_list_vendor as $products_list) { ?>
         <p><?php echo $products_list['vproduct_id']; ?></p>
         <p>- - - - - - - - - -</p>
     <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Предполагаемая причина 500-ой ошибки. Опечатка в конструкции `foreach` (у вас `forech`).

Comment: Ошибка 500 осталась. Может дело в скул запросе??

Comment: @privetsh В вопросе не весь ваш код. Конкретно этот участок не похоже, что содержит ошибку.

Comment: Может не по теме но! Можно сделать запрос на подобие массива?

Comment: @privetsh, не понял, чего вы хотите

Comment: в общем я установил на опенкарт 2 модуль мультивендор, у которого нет возможности на самом сайте (не админка) выводить  всех продавцов и их товары, нет возможности смотреть карточку какого либо продавца и какие у него товары. у меня получилось сделать чтоб краткая информация о продавце выводилась в карточке товара, который он добавил, получилось сделать отдельную страницу продавца с информацией о нем, теперь на этой странице нужно вывести всего его товары.

Comment: @privetsh, это совсем оффтоп. Оформите это как новый вопрос, с примером того, что вы сделали сами и ссылкой на упомянутый модуль.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561102/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B