# не получается получить данные из базы

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Я установил на опенкарт 2 модуль мультивендор, у которого нет возможности на самом сайте (не админка) выводить  всех продавцов и их товары, нет возможности смотреть карточку какого либо продавца и какие у него товары. у меня получилось сделать чтоб краткая информация о продавце выводилась в карточке товара, который он добавил, получилось сделать отдельную страницу продавца с информацией о нем, теперь на этой странице нужно вывести всего его товары.

Для этого нужно задействовать три таблицы:

- в первой `vendor` хранятся поля с id продавца и id продуктов,
- вторая  таблица `product` с данными продукта
- и в третьей таблице `product_description` нужно выбрать только наименование товара.

У одного продавца из таблицы `vendor` может быть, например, три товара с соответствующими id, и нужно учитывая эти id вытащить данные товара из таблиц `product` и `product_description` и эти все данные записать в один массив чтоб потом в цикле вывести все товары данного продавца на его странице.

то что я сделал...

```
$vproducts = array();
$sql_products_data = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count_id; $i++) {
    $sql_products_data[] = $this->db->query("select product_id, image, price, name from " . DB_PREFIX . "product, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description where " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id'] . " and " . DB_PREFIX . "product.product_id = " . $query['vproduct_id']);
 }

 foreach ($sql_products_data as $result) {
     if ($result) {
        $vproducts['prod_id'] = $result['product_id'];
        $vproducts['prod_image'] = $result['image'];
        $vproducts['prod_price'] = $result['price'];
        $vproducts['prod_name'] = $result['name'];
     }
 }


 if ($vendor_products) {
     foreach ($vendor_products as $result) {
        $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_id'] = $result['prod_id'];
        $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_image'] =     $result['prod_image'];
        $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_price'] = $result['prod_price'];
        $data['products_list_vendor']['vproduct_name'] = $result['prod_name'];

     }
 }


 <div id="vendor_products">
   <?php forech($products_list_vendor as $products_list) { ?>
     <p><?php echo $products_list['vproduct_id']; ?></p>
     <p>- - - - - - - - - -</p>
    <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: А ошибки в коде так и не поправили, на которые я вам указывал ранее

Comment: нет нет исправил в файлах, и все равно 500

Comment: исправьте и тут, а если вам помог мой ответ - примите его.

Comment: перепроверил еще раз, все равно ошибка 500

Comment: С ошибкой 500 разобрался написав в хостинг, ну а на странице продавца следующие ошибки ...   http://shopdemo.byethost32.com/index.php?route=information/vendor&vendor_id=3.   Код остался этот же который тут приведен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще раз всем привет и большое спасибо тем кто помогал, но! Получилось разобраться и самому, как оказалось, все оказалось намного проще... Нааа много! Итак, для моей ситуации которая описана выше реализация следующая:
 В файле модели пишем такой код... (тут я исправил сам запрос, именно такой о котором спрашивал у вас)

```
public function getProductsForVendor() {
    $query = $this->db->query("
        select p.product_id, 
                    p.image,
                    p.price, 
                    pd.name
        from ".DB_PREFIX."product p,
             ".DB_PREFIX."product_description pd,
             ".DB_PREFIX."vendor v
        where 
            p.product_id= v.vproduct_id
        and
            pd.product_id = v.vproduct_id
        and
            v.vendor = ".(int)$this->request->get['vendor_id']);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

В файле контроллера...

```
$vproducts_data_info = $this->model_catalog_vendor->getProductsForVendor();

foreach ($vproducts_data_info as $result) {
    $data['vendor_products_info'][] = array(
        'prod_id' => $result['product_id'],
        'prod_image' => $result['image'],
        'prod_price' => $result['price'],
        'prod_name' => $result['name']
    );
}
```

И сам вывод на страницу...

```
<div id="vendor_products"> 
        <?php foreach($vendor_products_info as $list) { ?>
            <p><?php echo $list['prod_id']; ?></p> 
            <p><?php echo $list['prod_image']; ?></p> 
            <p><?php echo $list['prod_price']; ?></p> 
            <p><?php echo $list['prod_name']; ?></p> 
            <p>- - - - - - - - - -</p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Вывод до боли приметивен исключительно для проверки работы модели и контроллера. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас в коде несколько проблем:

1.1) Данные из нескольких таблиц лучше обьеденить через JOIN

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN providers ON providers.id = products.provider_id
WHERE providers.status = "active"
```

1.2) Если есть массив то можно сделат 1 запрос.

```
// SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
$idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (%s)",
    join(", ", $idList)
);
```

2) Для форматирования строк запроса лучше использовать функции а не конкотенацию. Это позволит сильно уменшить количество синтасических ошибок и не путаться в скобках.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM %s.%s",
    DB_PREFIX,
    $tableName
);
```

3) Для передачи параметра в запрос лучше использовать Prepared Statements. Не уверен позволяет ли ваш обект его использовать.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
// Bonus: SQL Injection safe!!!
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = ?");
$db->execute($GET['name']);

// or
$idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$qMarks = array_fill(0, count($idList), "?");

// SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (%s)",
    join(", ",  $qMarks)
);

$db->prepare($sql);
$db->execute($idList);
```

4) Лучше разделить код и вывод данных.

5) У вас еще переменные скачут

`$vproducts` => `$vendor_products`

`$data['products_list_vendor']` => `$products_list_vendor`.

Скорее в этом и проблема! Аккуратнее с копипастой.

Comment: Очень позновательно, спасибо , обязательно сохраню, но это не совсем то что мне сейчас нужно!

Comment: @privetsh У вас еще одна проблема переменные скачут `$vproducts` => `$vendor_products`  `$data['products_list_vendor']` => `$products_list_vendor`. Скорее в этом и проблема!

Comment: @privetsh Более точный ответ, в данном случае, это не помощь, а выполнение работы. За это надо платить ;).

Comment: С ошибкой 500 разобрался написав в хостинг, ну а на странице продавца следующие ошибки ... shopdemo.byethost32.com/index.php?route=information/…. Код остался этот же который тут приведен